# My PHP Random page generator has stopped working properly after 100,000 hits

Tags: php, random, generator

My website relies completely on a random page generator that loads a page from a text file list.  The code was kindly written by "lserni" on the forum.  The script has been working perfectly the last few days, and it's happily processed over 100,000 page views in 3 days!

I noticed today however that it seems to have stopped working properly.  If you are a brand new visitor to the page, or you've cleared your internet cache/cookies etc -  When you load the page for the first time, it doesn't randomly generate a page.. it just shows a BLANK page.  If you then refresh the page, the script works perfectly.  I just can't get my head round it, but it's now resulted in a large drop in traffic!  Hope you can help:

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['urlist']))       // Do we know the user?
        $_SESSION['urlist'] = array();     // No, start with empty list
    if (empty($_SESSION['urlist']))        // Is the list empty?
    {
        $_SESSION['urlist'] = file("linklist.txt");   // Fill it.
        $safe = array_pop($_SESSION['urlist']);
        shuffle($_SESSION['urlist']);           // Shuffle the list
        array_push($_SESSION['urlist'], $safe);
    }
    $url = trim(array_pop($_SESSION['urlist']));
    header("Location: $url");
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you have this running?

Comment: What is the absolute first row in *linklist.txt*? That row is always the first URL used.

Comment: Emil: The link on the first row is working perfectly, so that's not the problem. 

Brad: I'd love to provide a link, but the content is NSFW, and I don't want to be removed from this site! If I'm allowed to post that, then I will. I really can't understand what's gone wrong but it's extremely frustrating. All I've changed on the site recently is adding Twitter and Facebook social buttons, but those are on the pages within linklist.txt. Nothing has been changed on the index.php random page generator (the code which I pasted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the LAST item in the file that's used first if there is no session data.

```
{
    $safe = array_pop($_SESSION['urlist']); // gets item at the END of the array
    shuffle($_SESSION['urlist']);
    array_push($_SESSION['urlist'], $safe); // puts item at the END of the array
}
$url = trim(array_pop($_SESSION['urlist']));// gets item at the END of the array
```

So if you introduced a newline in your textfile at the end, it may be your issue.

Comment: You are a GENIUS. Thank you so much for that.  I must have hit enter on the text file after adding the last page, which put the blank line there! Thank you tigrang.

Comment: No problem. You may want to use  `file('linklist.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` to avoid it happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, after the `header` call, add some HTML that explains where the user is being redirected to. All being well nobody will ever see it, but it could help diagnose why the user gets an empty page.